# При подключении jquery в сайт встраивается реклама в iframe, как убрать?

Tags: jquery, iframe, реклама

Подключаю jquery - на сайте в шапке через раз при загрузке появляется баннер с рекламой (см. скриншот). Убираю jquery - пропадает баннер. jquery свежий с jquery.com, пробовал и jquery, и jquery.min - результат один. В коде страницы виден "левый" iframe. В самом jquery не могу найти, где и что убрать (jquery скачал, лежит в папке с сайтом). В интернете тоже не нашел ни одного похожего случая, что странно. Прошу подсказать, что делать?
Хостинг spaceweb
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Задайте вопрос в тех. поддержку хостинга. Я как то пользуясь ispmanager, лишился .css файла(не нужно спрашивать как это вышло, я сам не знаю, и решать это до сих пор не планирую). Написал в тех. поддержку, ребята все нашли за мгновение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у тебя Ростелеком (не знаю за других, но сам лично сталкивался с Ростелекомовской рекламой), то скорей всего это провайдер встраивает рекламу в незащищённое соединение http://..., переведи сайт на https://..., другого способа нет

вот статья на Habr https://habr.com/ru/post/493402/

Comment: Благодарю, действительно помогло!